# How to prevent opening multiple popup windows?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is next.

I want to prevent opening second popup window, while first one is active. I want achieve this on more than 2 windows (modals), let's say 5 or 6.

Does anyone know how can i achieve that?

I appreciate your help.

Here is the code:

**-HTML:**

```
<!-- Buttons -->
<button class="trigger_1">Image 1</button>
<button class="trigger_2">Image 2</button>
<button class="trigger_3">Image 3</button>
<!-- / Buttons -->

<!-- Popup 1 -->
<div id="popup_1">

<!-- Popup 1 img -->
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-CmBgofK7QzU/TVj3u3N1h2I/AAAAAAAADN8/OszBhGvvXRU/s640/tumblr_lg7h9gpbtP1qap9qio1_500.jpeg" />
<!-- / Popup 1 img -->

<!-- Button placeholder -->
<div id="button_placeholder">

<!-- Button placeholder button -->
<button class="close x_1">Close [ x ]</button>
<!-- / Button placeholder button -->

</div>
<!-- / Button placeholder -->

</div>
<!-- / Popup 1 -->

<!-- Popup 2 -->
<div id="popup_2">

<!-- Popup 2 img -->
<img src="http://7.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kuuspiVq8D1qzn34eo1_500.jpg" />
<!-- / Popup 2 img -->

<!-- Button placeholder -->
<div id="button_placeholder">

<!-- Button placeholder button -->
<button class="close x_2">Close [ x ]</button>
<!-- / Button placeholder button -->

</div>
<!-- / Button placeholder -->

</div>
<!-- / Popup 2 -->

<!-- Popup 3 -->
<div id="popup_3">

<!-- Popup 3 img -->
<img src="http://29.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ljyn38rIqC1qg2exfo1_500.jpg" />
<!-- / Popup 3 img -->

<!-- Button placeholder -->
<div id="button_placeholder">

<!-- Button placeholder button -->
<button class="close x_3">Close [ x ]</button>
<!-- / Button placeholder button -->

</div>
<!-- / Button placeholder -->

</div>
<!-- / Popup 3 -->
```

**-CSS:**

```
/* Popup 1 */
#popup_1 {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 33%;
height: auto;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
z-index: 100;
display: none; }

/* Popup 2 */
#popup_2 {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 33%;
height: auto;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
z-index: 100;
display: none; }

/* Popup 3 */
#popup_3 {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 33%;
height: auto;
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(51,51,51,0.1);
z-index: 100;
display: none; }

/* Popup img */
img {
float: left;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto; }

/* Button placeholder */
#button_placeholder {
float: left;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto; }

/* Button placeholder button */
#button_placeholder .close {
margin: 15px auto;
padding: 7px 9px;
font-size: 16px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #ff48a1;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
border: none;
outline: none;
display: block;
cursor: pointer; }

/* Button placeholder button (hover effect) */
#button_placeholder .close:hover {
background-color: #333; }
```

**-JavaScript:**

```
// When everything is ready...
$( document ).ready(function() {

// Modal 1 mechanism:
$('.trigger_1').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
modal1();
});

$('.x_1').click(function() {
$('#popup_1').fadeOut() });

function modal1() {
$('#popup_1').fadeIn(); }
// End.


// Modal 2 mechanism:
$('.trigger_2').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
modal2();
});

$('.x_2').click(function() {
$('#popup_2').fadeOut() });

function modal2() {
$('#popup_2').fadeIn(); }
// End.


// Modal 3 mechanism:
$('.trigger_3').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
modal3();
});

$('.x_3').click(function() {
$('#popup_3').fadeOut() });

function modal3() {
$('#popup_3').fadeIn(); }
// End.

});
// End.
```

Regards, Milan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these condition to prevent multiple popup opening:

```
function modal1() {
    if ($("#popup_2").is(":hidden")){
        $('#popup_1').fadeIn();
    }
    else{/*do something*/}
}


function modal2() { 
    if ($("#popup_1").is(":hidden")){
        $('#popup_2').fadeIn();
    }
    else{/*do something*/}
}
```

**Better way to do it is by using classes:**

```
function modal(element){
    if ($(".pop_up_open").length == 0){
         $(element).fadeIn();
         $(element).addClass("pop_up_open");
    }
    else{/*do something*/}
}
function modalClose(){/*this function will run when you want to close function*/
         $(".pop_up_open").fadeOut();
         $(".pop_up_open").removeClass("pop_up_open");
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b00915vp/3/)**

Instead of many function use these function to pop_up a element you want to open and close.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.trigger_1').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal("#popup_1");
    });
    $('.x_1').click(function () {
        modalClose();
    });
    $('.trigger_2').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal("#popup_2");
    });
    $('.x_2').click(function () {
        modalClose();
    });
    $('.trigger_3').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal("#popup_3");
    });
    $('.x_3').click(function () {
        modalClose();
    });
});
```

Comment: But tell me bro just one more thing, what if i have lets say 5 windows (modals)? Thanks for help.

Comment: You need to use class that is applied to a pop-up that is open and removed this class when pop_up is closed. If the class `$(class).length>0` then do not open any pop-up.

Comment: Thanks bro, can you write it somehow? Thanks for help!

Comment: Bro this doesn't work with more than 2 windows, code above work, but this below doesn't (like i said, with more than 2 windows)?

Comment: The below code will work. It depends how are you using it. If you have doubt I'll create a fiddle with example.

Comment: Thanks bro, it will help me a lot! :)

Comment: Just add one more button and one more window (modal) and that's it, than put the jscript and try.

Comment: Sorry for not updating fiddle soon got struck in something important at work. Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/b00915vp/3/. Give it a try.

Comment: yes it's great, but i found another solution. Thanks for your time, i hope you can write it here so i can mark it like accepted answer. Thanks bro!

Comment: You are welcome and good to hear that you have find other solution by yourself. I have updated my answer, if you think it solves your problem than accept it. :)